# Calculating and applying a rotation interpolation in real-time

Tags: rotations, angular-acceleration

I'm trying to mimic the pan behavior of a DMX moving head so that I can simulate it as closely as possible. A straightforward acceleration/deceleration algorithm doesn't work, even after repeated trial & error with the parameters and there's always something off about the acceleration, deceleration or both.

So I tried measuring the acceleration curve. I set up a camera and prepared the moving head to rotate within its field of view: -170.5° to -20.12° (the weird values are because I'm converting from DMX values in range 0-255). The input change is a sudden one, so all of the movement speed comes from the mover itself. On the wall I taped six Xs to divide the trajectory into fifths and recorded the trajectory. By recording it together with a frame counter, I  was able to get the amount of frames each fifth of the trajectory took. Converting those to seconds and degrees per second gives:

-170.5° to -140.8°: 0.5667s| 52.4087°/s

-140.8° to -111.2°: 0.15s | 198°/s

-111.2° to -81.53°: 0.1833s| 161.8658°/s

-81.53° to -51.88°: 0.2s | 148.25°/s

-51.88° to -20.12°: 0.7s | 45.3714°/s

Now, I can put all of this data into mycurvefit.com and get a 4th polynomial curve equation, but I'm not sure how to actually implement it. So my questions are

a) How can I calculate the acceleration and deceleration values given these data?

b) How can I apply those forcoes at random short time intervals where all I know is the current rotation, the current speed, and the target rotation keeping in mind that the target rotation can change at any moment?

Comment: Taking some distance with the peculiar software you use (that most people don't know here), have you heard about SLERPS in the framework of rotation interpolations like in [this document](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6a3fb145155ba84709c8629c7eba0d243597bb88) ?

Comment: @Jean Marie My apologies. I've made the question more general. 

That paper looks a bit too advanced for me. There seems to be a slerp function in the peculiar software I'm using, so I'll try using that for starters...